# How to setup JTA with multiple XA datasoures for Spring JPA?

Tags: spring, jpa, jta

`Spring JPA 4.2.1`

Trying to setup JTA with 2 XA datasoures looks like below but gets `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`

"No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: emf_1,emf_2"

```
<bean id="emf_1"
    class="...LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="xa_1" />
</bean>
<bean id="emf_2"
    class="...LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="xa_2" />
</bean>
```

```java
@Repository
public class DAO {
    @PersistenceContext@Qualifier("emf_1")
    private EntityManager em_1;
    @PersistenceContext@Qualifier("emf_2")
    private EntityManager em_2;
    /*...*/
}
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Solution**

It works below now,

```
<bean class="...LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="xa_1" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu_1" />
</bean>
<bean class="...LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="xa_2" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu_2" />
</bean>
```

---

```java
@Repository
public class DAO {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu_1")
    private EntityManager em_1;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu_2")
    private EntityManager em_2;
    /*...*/
}
```

---

```
<persistence-unit name="pu_1" transaction-type="JTA">
...
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="pu_2" transaction-type="JTA">
...
</persistence-unit>
```